# Should I use React Router redirect OR package.json "homepage" property for setting a relative path as homepage in my React app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, package.json

#### TL;DR - I want my React app to start with a relative path *domain.com/tweets*

Hello everyone, I'm creating a React app that fetches tweets from Twitter API.

Because the whole app is just an SPA built in react, I figured it would be wrong to create an empty homepage with a link to navigate to the tweets page, instead of just displaying the tweets right away as the "homepage". Again, currently, displaying tweets is the only thing the app does.

Therefore, I was looking for a way to start my app with the path "/tweets/" right after the domain name.

I know there are **two options** I can use but I'm not sure which one to use:

1. package.json "homepage": "/tweets" property
2. React router Navigate to="/tweets"  component

I like the behavior of the redirect more than the package.json homepage option because I don't have a homepage really, it prevents the user from trying to access domain.com and instead redirects them to domain.com/tweets.

**#EDIT 1**

In your answer, please note I'm using React Router V6, as some of the previous features you may know might not be relevant anymore.

###### What option should I choose? Am I missing anything? Will this give me problems when uploading to production?

###### Here's my current solution:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/tweets" element={<App />}>
        <Route path=":pageNumber" />
      </Route>
      <Route
        path="*"
        element={<Navigate to="/tweets"/>}
      />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

###### EDIT #2 - Here's the updated code

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/tweets/:currentPageNumber" element={<App />}/>
      <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/tweets/1" />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your React app ever going to have more than one page? If the answer is no, then I don't see any point in using any routing at all.

The two options I would suggest are:

1. Use `"homepage": "."` entry in `package.json` file so any routes you do use can work relative from where the app is deployed. Deploy your app to a `"/tweets"` subdirectory on your server. If you decide later you do need to add other pages and routes to the app, specify the `basename` prop to the router component you choose to use.

   ```
   <BrowserRouter basename="/tweets">
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
         <Route path=":pageNumber" />
       </Route>
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
   ```
2. Use `"homepage": "."` entry in `package.json` file so any routes used work relative from the app deployment location. Deploy the app to the root directory and handle redirecting to a `"/tweets"` route.

   ```
   <BrowserRouter>
     <Routes>
       <Route path="/tweets" element={<App />}>
         <Route path=":pageNumber" />
       </Route>
       <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/tweets" replace />} />
     </Routes>
   </BrowserRouter>
   ```

See [Building for Relative Paths](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer.
1. As for your first claim regarding the necessity of routing in the app "I don't see any point in using routing at all", I use routing to present different tweets on every page. It's an SPA with pagination, so the page number in the URL is used as a param in the React Routing system along with the useNavigate hook.
2. Regarding basename - is it supported in React Router V6? I see some complaints about it https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7128
3. Your 2nd option is probably what I'm doing now. I'll stick to it I suppose.

Comment: @EstheticNerd Yes, `basename` is a supported prop on ***every*** router component in RRDv6, I double checked before answering to ensure this.